# Админка на React, это реально?

Tags: reactjs, админка

Задача: сделать магазин с админкой, где можно редактировать каталоги, меню, добавлять/удалять страницы и т д.

Реально ли это сделать на React? Если да, то какие "велосипеды" использовать?

Comment: 1. Вполне реально; 
2.В зависимости от целей и сложности. Можно даже без "велосипедов" писать.

Comment: Очень даже реально, проще и быстрее, занимаюсь сейчас именно этим, только на VUE(Nuxt)

Answer (score 1):

Только с помощью реакт этого сделать нельзя, так как все данные в нём грубо говоря доступны любому. Вам нужнен бекенд с API где будут храниться данные пользователей "под защитой" и который будет решать - кто что может делать.

Рекомендую посмотреть в сторону next.js